# App is draining battery by frequently refreshing in the background

Tags: android

I'm working on an app and after installing it on my phone and leaving it in the background for an hour or so, my phone showed me an alert with

```
 App is draining battery by frequently refreshing in the background
```

Does it mean that something causes one or more of the activities to constantly resume? How can I test it to track down the problem? Should I overwrite onActivityResume method in each activity and log something?
Could it be firebase listeners?

What could be an efficient strategy to deal with this problem?

Comment: are you destroying(by using `finish();` method) your activity after use? can you post some code so we can help?

Comment: Is there any background service started within your application? Like start a GPS service in the background and didn't stop it?

Comment: I just checked and I always finish an activity when starting a new one unless the new one should be on top of the first one. About the GPS service, I do remove the listener once the location is retrived and btw my phone displays a different message for frequent location request, something like "App is draining battery by constantly requesting for location".
Thanks again